# AngularJS $state.go executes before previous statement execution completes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngresource

I am using AngularJS, ui-router and $resource for RESTful webservices.

A button in html view is clicked that calls below function i.e. $scope.login(). Consequently a REST service (through $resource) is called and returns a user in case user/pass are correct,

```
$scope.login = function() {
myfactory.get({
        email: $scope.user.email,
        password: $scope.user.password
    },function(user) {
        accessmgr.grantAccess(user);      //Line of interest - loi1
        $state.go('app.dashboard-v1');    //Line of interest2 - loi2
    }, function(x) {
        if (x.status == 401)
            $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
        else
            $scope.authError = 'Server Error! Are you connected to internet?';
    });
}
```

in case above successfully executes, another factory function (loi1 above) is called to store user instance in $localStorage as below;

```
myapp.factory('accessmgr', function($localStorage) {
    //var User = {};
    return {grantAccess: function(usr) {
            $localStorage.user = usr;
        }
    }});
```

and ui-router $scope.go(...) takes the user to dashboard.

**Problem:**
*Sometimes* $state.go(...) executes before accessmgr.grantAccess(...) causing exceptions as the new state reads user from $localStorage that is not yet written. Reload the page manually solves the problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Wait for the promise returned from ``grantAccess`` then execute $state.go like ``accessmgr.grantAccess(user).then(function(response){
        $state.go('app.dashboard-v1'); })``

Comment: I think promise/then is only for callbacks like for $http or $resource? In my case its just another function saving user to $localStorage. Anyhow, I tried it but error is reported on console of chrome `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` and same for $promise.then `TypeError: Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined`

Comment: Promises can be used with any async service, as long as service is promise-based (and $localStorage is not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngStorage's $localStorage cannot be referred directly without using watchers (not recommended as per [here](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/tree/0.3.9), alternatively it can to be passed as a reference to hook to $scope as mentioned as recommended approach [here](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/tree/0.3.9).

For me, I was using $localStorage through a factory and I tied it to rootScope as below;

```
$rootScope.$storage = $localStorage;
```

and consequently

```
myapp.factory('accessmgr', function($localStorage) {
  $rootScope.$storage = $localStorage;
  return {
    grantAccess: function(usr) {
        $rootScope.$storage.user = usr;
      },
    getUser: function() {
        return $rootScope.$storage.user;
      }
  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage itself works in synchronous manner, but ngStorage's $localstorage doesn't. The latter is intended to be used in conjunction with scope and [is tied to Angular digest cycles](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/blob/0.3.9/ngStorage.js#L187). My guess is that

```
myapp.factory('accessmgr', function($localStorage) {
    return {grantAccess: function(usr) {
            $localStorage.user = usr;
            $localStorage.$apply();
        }
    }});
```

may help. ngStorage doesn't really shine when being used like this, probably JS generic library like [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) applies better.

A good alternative is to use model that acts as single source of truth and dumps the data to localStorage under the hood. Depending on the scale of the project, [js-data-angular](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-angular) can be considered a solid solution for that.

Comment: $localStorage.$apply() is throwing an error as ngStorage localStorage doesnt seem to have this function. `TypeError: Cannot read property '$apply....`. Anyhow thanks for pointing me to right direction as I was actually using ngStorage's localStorage and I didnt mention it in my question. Below answer is what solved my problem.

Comment: Its API may have changed with time, but in recent versions [there is $apply](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/blob/master/ngStorage.js#L158) which is meant to sync storage data immediately.