# AngularJS : promise

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, promise, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use promises in my app , however I'm not sure if i do it right. The reason I use promise is because ,my app gets input of username and it needs to find it in the local storage, if it doesn't exist it makes a consloe.log(err).

the code:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(conUser) {
            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                // do a thing, possibly async, then…
                resolve("Stuff worked!",
                conUser.countConnect++,
                $localstorage.setObject('a',$scope.Users),
                $scope.User = $filter('filter')($scope.Users, { userName: conUser.u})[0],
                console.log($scope.User.userName),
                $scope.User.connected = 'true',
                $scope.User.countConnect ++,
                $localstorage.setObject('a',$scope.Users)
                //// $scope.Users.push(conUser);
                );

                reject(Error("It broke"));
            });
            promise.then(function(result) {
                console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
            });

        });
```

It works but, is there a better way to do it ? I'm not sure that it should look like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a promise here as you aren't doing anything asynchronous. Something like this should work

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(conUser) {
var matchingUser = $filter('filter')($scope.Users, { userName: conUser.u})[0];
    if (matchingUser) {
        //handel user found
    } else {
        //handel user not found
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No promises are needed here.

From [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32460274/3731501):

> localStorage itself works in synchronous manner, but ngStorage's
>   $localstorage doesn't. The latter is intended to be used in
>   conjunction with scope and is tied to Angular digest cycles.

There's no problems with synchronization while the scope and `$q` promises (they are synced to the scope) are involved. And UI-Bootstrap uses `$q` under hood. And keep away from `Promise` even for async things in Angular, stick to `$q` instead.